Is there a way to vacuum a Unqlite database file?
I came across this database (unqlite), which is an embedded no-SQL key-value store database that is modeled a lot on the SQLite C API. The documentation isn't great though and I was wondering if there's a way to defragment/vacuum the database file like in SQLite.

@karel It's hard to get info on this. I'm reading through the doc but it obviously isn't as ample as the SQLite docs and I'm struggling. I call unqlite_kv_store to store my key and value, and then the program exits. On my disk I notice there's the database file and the journal file. The database file is empty and the journal file is 512 bytes, but it just has zeros in it. I haven't given the flag UNQLITE_OPEN_OMIT_JOURNALING so I expected it to be ACID compliant.

@karel "However there are workarounds" - workarounds like what? I don't think recreating the database is the equivalent of a sqlite vacuum, or is it? Recreating you mean getting each value from each key and inserting into a new database, I don't think that's guaranteed to be "vacuumed"
